# How to fetch data into array 1 from array 2, based on particular key value?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays.

```
$primary = array(
           [0] => array(
                     'name' => 'PPT Shop',
                     'place_id'   => '1000',
                     'category' => '220,221',
                     'address' =>
                   ),  
           [1] => array(
                     'name' => 'Meat Shop',
                     'place_id'   => '1001',
                     'category' => '220,221'
                     'address' =>
                   ),
           [2] => array(
                     'name' => 'Bikini Shop',
                     'place_id'   => '1010',
                     'category' => '100,102'
                     'address' =>
                   ),
           [3] => array(
                     'name' => 'Knife Shop',
                     'place_id'   => '1012',
                     'category' => '1,3'
                     'address' =>
                   )
)

$moredata = array(
           [0] => array(
                     'id'   => '1000',
                     'category' => '900,901'
                     'address' => '35 Lawrence Park',
                     'phone'  => '9000000099'
                   ),  
           [1] => array(
                     'id'   => '1001',
                     'category' => '909,300'
                     'address' => '39 Park Avenue',
                   ),
           [2] => array(
                     'id'   => '1010',
                     'category' => '50,45'
                     'address' => '35 Trump Park',
                     'phone'  => '8900000099'
                   )
)
```

I want to compare each data of $moredata with each data of $primary, and check if the `place_id` from $primary exists in $moredata. If it matches, then the corresponding records of that particular key will be updated. For example,

```
$newPrimary = array(
           [0] => array(
                     'name' => 'PPT Shop',
                     'place_id'   => '1000',
                     'category' => '220,221,900,901',
                     'address' => '35 Lawrence Park',
                     'phone'  => '9000000099'
                   ),  
           [1] => array(
                     'name' => 'Meat Shop',
                     'place_id'   => '220,221,1001',
                     'category' => '220,221,909,300',
                     'address' => '39 Park Avenue',
                   ),
           [2] => array(
                     'name' => 'Bikini Shop',
                     'place_id'   => '1010',
                     'category' => '100,102,50,45'
                     'address' => '35 Trump Park',
                     'phone'  => '8900000099'
                   ),
           [3] => array(
                     'name' => 'Knife Shop',
                     'place_id'   => '1012',
                     'category' => '1,3'
                     'address' =>
                   )
)
```

**place_id(1000)** of **primary** matches with **id(1000)** of **moredata**, so the **place_id(1000)** of **newPrimary** is like this:-

```
array(
     'name' => 'PPT Shop',
     'place_id'   => '1000',
     'category' => '220,221,900,901', // the categories get concated
     'address' => '35 Lawrence Park',
     'phone'  => '9000000099'
)
```

However, for **place_id(1001)** of primary doesn't have phone field, so the id(1001) of newPrimary is like this:-

```
array(
     'name' => 'Meat Shop',
     'place_id'   => '1001',
     'category' => '220,221,909,300', 
     'address' => '39 Park Avenue',
)
```

**place_id(1012)** has no match, so it remains unchanged.

How can I create an array similar to **newPrimary**? It would be better if we can append the fields from **moredata** to the corresponding record from **primary**. I achieved the same using double foreach loop. I want to achieve this is a way to have lesser execution time.

```
foreach($primary as $key_fs => $prm)
{
    foreach($moredata as $key_place => $pc)
    {
        if($prm['place_id'] == $pc['id'])
        {
            if(isset($pc['address']) && !empty($pc['address']))
                $primary[$key_fs]['address']  = $pc['address'];


            if(isset($pc['phone']) && !empty($pc['phone']))
                $primary[$key_fs]['phone']  = $pc['phone'];

            if(isset($pc['category']) && !empty($pc['category']))
               $primary[$key_fs]['category']  .= ','.$pc['category'];

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note:- The two arrays will have same dimension, but may not have same order.

Comment: Can you include the arrays as Json or var_export instead?

Comment: Tip: you can drop the `isset` check as `empty` returns false when a variable is not set (without throwing an error)

Comment: @Andreas, where to include it?

Comment: In the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_column` to make the 2 arrays into multidimensional array. Use `array_replace_recursive` to merge the arrays.

You can use `array_values` if you want a simple array instead of multi dimensional output.

```
$primary = //Your array
$moredata  = //Your array
$result = array_replace_recursive (array_column($primary, null, 'id') ,array_column($moredata, null, 'id') );
$result = array_values($result); //To convert the multidimensional array to simple array
```

---

**Update:**

You can use `array_column` to make a temp array for `$moredata`. This will make it easier to check if the id exist. Use the `foreach` to loop thru the array. If id exist on `$moredata`, simply concatenate the category.

```
$newMoreData = array_column($moredata, null, 'id');
$newPrimary = array();

foreach( $primary as $val ) {
    if ( isset( $newMoreData[$val['place_id']] ) ) {
        $temp = array_merge( $val, $newMoreData[$val['place_id']] );
        $temp['category'] = $val['category'] . ',' . $newMoreData[$val['place_id']]['category'];
        unset($temp['id']);
        $newPrimary[] = $temp;
    } else {
        $newPrimary[] = $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. But I have one more requirement which I forgot to add.

Comment: What is the additional requirement? :)

Comment: hello @Eddie, I added the requirement

Comment: @Saswat Is the category needs to be unique on the result? Or it can like `2000,1000,2000`?

Comment: same category can stay twice

Comment: Hello @Eddie, I still have a question.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What if 'id' fields have different name, but same value? Say, the `$primary` key is 'place_id' and in `$moredata` it is 'id'. How can I match them?

Comment: Do you want both `place_id` and `id` on the final array? @Saswat

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: You can just use `unset` to remove the id. Please check the updated code